# Confused by Masstransit ReceiveFrom method and consumer behaviour

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

I want to create a queue with RabbitMq where I will be sending some messages on one side and receive in another application. I'am doing so with following code:

```
return ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
        {
            var uriString = string.Format(@"rabbitmq://{0}/{1}/{2}?prefetch={3}", host, virtualHost, queueName,
                prefetch < 1 ? 1 : prefetch);
            x.UseRabbitMq(r => r.ConfigureHost(new MessageUrn(uriString), h =>
            {
                h.SetUsername(user);
                h.SetPassword(password);
                h.SetRequestedHeartbeat(3);

            }));

            x.ReceiveFrom(uriString);

            x.UseJsonSerializer<ServiceBusConfigurator>();

            f(x);
        });
```

MessageUrn uri and ReceiveFrom should have the same uri, otherwise uri specified for  ReceiveFrom  method determine bus  endpoint.  But it means that my publisher is also consumer of the same queue. When there are no receiver all messages are go to queuename_error queue. When there is a receiver then everything seems to be ok.

What I'm doing wrong? I understand why messages go to error queue --  because publisher is not subscribed on them but in the same time he is a consumer, hence 
error situation occurs. Is it possible to recover messages from error queue, when receiver is (re)started?

masstransit is 2.10.0.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest for you to upgrade masstransit to <= 3.0.0 version, it has better API. Here is documentation for masstransit v3 and up : http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/

Comment: I can't use later versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ReceiveFrom()` address should be unique for each service, and only shared when the services have the same consumers with the same message types being consumed. The only common thing between services using the same RabbitMQ server is the host (and virtual host, if used). Otherwise, they must be different.

And yes, they're going into the error queue because the publisher is not subscribed to them. Give your publisher a different queue name, and the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Still I can't get it -- why should I specify ReceiveFrom() if I only want to send messages? Why uri in ConfigureHost method is not enough? Also, when I specify to different uri string ( one for ConfigureHost  and one for ReceiveFrom) then messages will be send to queue specified by ReceiveFrom method. Quite strange...

Comment: It is an artifact of the age and evolution of the v2 API. The V3 api makes a lot more sense, but you said you can't upgrade, so, you're stuck with it.

Comment: If v3 can help to avoid this, I will try to migrate. I supposed that it is RMQ specific.